# Contact Form 7 unable to submit by AJAX so redirects to 404

Tags: ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am working on a [build for a new website](http://wp.rapidataservices.tutchhq.co.uk/contact/) which includes the Wordpress plugin Contact Form 7 to handle the submission of the form & (is supposed) to display a response via AJAX.

I simply cannot get the AJAX side of this to work. Upon submission the form works fine, but the page reloads and displays the 404 page... not cool!

Following the [FAQ page](http://contactform7.com/why-isnt-my-ajax-contact-form-working-correctly/) I have run a number of tests. I can confirm:

1. The page is correctly referencing `wp_head` and `wp_footer`.
2. The page has no JavaScript errors in the console.
3. Whilst the page has one or two validation errors (created by another plugin), I don't believe this to be the issue. I have attempted to test this by stripping out everything except the form (and the header & footer).
4. I have deactivated each plug-in for conflicts & the problem persists.
5. I have flushed the permalinks (by re-saving via `settings > permalinks`) & tested.
6. I have created new form instances & tested.
7. Reinstalled the Contact Form 7 plug-in & tested.

After all that I'm still no closer to a solution. Can anyone shed any light on this issue as I'm very keen to avoid using an alternative plugin.

I can provide more details if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and on review of the page source, it seems that the plugin is creating the relevant JS files... So I've no idea why the AJAX isn't firing!

Answer (score 0):

I tried clicking on the URL you provided for your website and it did not work.
I would check to ensure there are no conflicts with the jQuery as this could be the cause of the form not submitting with AJAX.

Comment: Ah this is a very old question. I've since found an alternative solution to Contact Form 7 as I've found it's very resource heavy. Thanks tho :D

Comment: @Sheixt So what is the solution haha? I've never encoutered this issue before(and I update approximately 30 websites per month). But the latest Contact Form 7 update causes this bug.